# How can i reach as variable of /src last folder in shell script?

Tags: android, shell, adb, ubuntu-12.04, pwd

this sh script is in `<project-dir>/w` that named "install.sh"

i want to catch my directory last name "bes" where is   `<project-dir>/src/com/seri/bes`

```
 #!bin/bash
```

i use `myendpath=${PWD##*/}`at this line but variable return "w";

```
myendpath=ls ../src/com/seri/
me="../bin/$myendpath-debug.apk"
adb uninstall com.seri.$myendpath
adb install $me
```

how can i reach name value `<project-dir>/src/com/seri/*` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!bin/sh  
my1=$(ls ../src/com/seri)
my2="../bin/$my1-debug.apk"
adb uninstall com.seri.$my1
adb install $my2
```

i did it..
its too usefull working with command line android